# A probabilistic approach of Prisioner's Dilemma

Tags: probability, game-theory

In a prison there were three prisoners, $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$. A draw had been made to give two of them a pardon. $A_1$ asked a guard (who knew the draw) the name of another prisoner who had been pardoned. The guard said that he couldn't do that, otherwise the probability that $A_1$ would be pardoned would change from $\frac{2}{3}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$. Is the guard correct? (sorry for my english)

At first the guard seems to be wrong to me.

But I've given a proof that he's correct:

Let $A_i$ be the event "$A_i$ has been pardoned".

Suppose, without loss of generality, that the guard told $A_1$ that $A_3$ has been forgiven.

$$P(A_1|A_3)=\frac{P(A_1\cap A_3)}{P(A_3)}$$

Note that $P(A_1\cap A_3)$ is the probability of $A_2^c$, which is $\frac{1}{3}$. And $P(A_3)=P(A_1^c)+P(A_2^c)=\frac{2}{3}$.Therefore,

$$P(A_1|A_3)=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

What's wrong?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your wording, but this seems very comparable to the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) (except with a prison theme). I might also add that while the question is framed as a dilemma faced by prisoners, it has very little to do with the [Prisoner's Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma).

Comment: @Shane, I agree with the fact that it has little to do with the original Prisoner's Dilemma, but I didn't name the exercise. And I also see how it's comparable with Monty Hall problem. And, in that language, $A_1$ cannot  "choose another door" once "one door was open", then tha probability of victory would still be 1/3. That's why I think the guard is wrong. But I gave this proof which says that he's right. Then, what's the answer?

Comment: This problem is, strictly speaking, underspecified.  We would also need to know, in the event that $A_1$ is not pardoned, how the guard decides whether to name $A_2$ or $A_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. The guard is not correct because the draw had already been made. If two names were being pulled from a hat and the first one was $A_3$, then the probability that $A_1$ would come up on the next draw would be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Note, however, that $A_1$'s probability of being pardoned is still $\frac{2}{3}$. This is because there is a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ of him being pardoned on the first draw followed by a probability of $\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}$ of being selected on the second draw for a total probability of $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: But what's wrong in my proof?

Comment: You are only considering the second draw given that the first draw was not $A_1$.

Answer (score 2):

The probability you want is not $P(A_1\mid A_3)$ but $P(A_1\mid G_3)$, where $G_3$ is the event that the guard tells you that $A_3$ was pardoned. We have

$$P(A_1\mid G_3)=\frac{P(A_1\cap G_3)}{P(G_3)}=\frac{P(A_1\cap G_3)}{P(A_1\cap G_3)+P(\overline A_1\cap G_3)}=\frac{P(\overline A_2)}{P(\overline A_2)+P(\overline A_1\cap G_3)}=\frac{\frac13}{\frac13+\frac16}=\frac23\;.$$